# Custom Facebook share button does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can somebody explain why my custom Facebook share button does not work?
Whenever I click the button it the share window just does not show up. 
I've tried it as html file on an actual webserver, and I've read everything in the facebook docs regarding the share button.

When using the [same code provided by facebook](http://www.fbrell.com/saved/2779dc018c325d85d650a3b723239650) it does work.

I do get [this error](http://prntscr.com/iqovjp) though when clicking on the button.

This is my code. (Without the CSS because its a bit more, If you need it I can add it.)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1"></script>

<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Share Dialog</h1>
</div>
<p>Click the button below to trigger a Share Dialog</p>
<button class="fill" id="fb-share-button">Share on Facebook</button>

<script>
document.getElementById('fb-share-button').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    display: 'popup',
    href: 'https://nureinberg.de',
  }, function(response){});
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the FB SDK,

This includes the `FB.init` function and having the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` element.

Check out this pen - it works just fine minus the App ID of course, but the popup portion works:

https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/MVKerM

I also added the version ID to the `sdk.js` script (`https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7`)

Comment: although the asynchronous way is the recommended one, he is using the synchronous version of the js sdk, so he does not really need FB.init.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've implemented it but its still not working, i've also added an own appID. Unfortunately not even the codepen works when adding the appID.

Comment: The app ID won't work because it's not authorized to run on the codepen.io domain, and I actually had removed the async init - and accidentally clicked save. I put it back in so the popup portion is still working again

Comment: It works now but is there a way to create a custom share button without having to register an appID for every website? @luschn

Comment: @AlexanderHoerl check out my answer, i have included some more details about that. also, it works with your code if you just add the app id in the url too.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a version and the App ID to the JS SDK source:

```
https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&appId=<your-app-id>
```

Although, i would recommend using the asynchronous way to load the JS SDK:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

**If you do not want to create an App, use sharer.php with a standard anchor-tag:**

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<encoded-url>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your answers. It works now with the following code.

I've also created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/alexanderhoerl/pen/xWwvwL) for it.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'your-app-id',
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.7'
  });

  FB.AppEvents.logPageView();

};

document.getElementById('fb-share-button').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    display: 'popup',
    href: window.location.href,
  }, function(response){});
}
```